# Compensating for the Shortcomings of Find.Execute in Office COM

Tags: powershell, office-interop

Given that `Find.Execute` does not allow for RegEx, is there any COM way to do this besides streaming the paragraphs out and stepping through them one by one?

I need to find a RegEx pattern in a Word document, **and preferably return the match**. Failing that, find a RegEx in a Word document and at least return $True so I can capture it.

N.B.: I realize that the reason `Find.Execute` is limited is due to it being a call to the "find text" dialog, but I'm hoping there's some similarly efficient way to search for patterns. `Find.Execute` is fairly quick, streaming out the text from the document as a range and then searching through that is not.

Answer (score 2):

When exactly did `Find.Execute` stop allowing for regular expressions?

```
$wd = New-Object -COM "Word.Application"

...

$fnd = $wd.Selection.Find

$fnd.Text = "..."  # replace with your pattern
$fnd.MatchWildcards = True
...
$fnd.Execute
```

The syntax is just a [little different](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/general/usingwildcards.htm) from standard regular expressions.

Comment: "When exactly did Find.Execute stop allowing for regular expressions?"
You answered this question: it never did. Wildcards are not regular expressions. In the times I have tooled around with them, they were not as capable as [regex] invocations, and had different enough syntax that learning them was a burden. However, for my use case, I suppose I'll bite the bullet and learn the details to regain the speed advantage.